# Scala typing: "Expected _$1, got T"

Tags: scala, generics

I have a Lift project with mixed Java-Scala code. The project has a JPA backend written in Java with EclipseLink, which is accessed by the Scala side, which uses Lift and Lift-NG.

On the Java side, I have the following relevant interfaces:

```
interface IEntity

interface IDAO<T extends IEntity> {
    void persist(T t);
}
```

On the Scala side, I have the following:

```
abstract class Binding[T <: IEntity] extends NgModel {
    def unbind: T
}

class BasicService[B <: Binding[_ <: IEntity]](serviceName: String, dataAccessObject: IDAO[_ <: IEntity]) {
    def persist(binding : B): Unit = {
        val entity = binding.unbind
        dataAccessObject.persist(entity)
    }
}
```

The purpose of this hierarchy is to let me create Service instances which handle a given Binding for entity E, which can also receive and use an appropriate DAO created to handle type E. For example:

```
// Java side
class Todo implements IEntity

class TodoManager implements IDAO<Todo>

// Scala side
case class TodoBinding extends Binding[Todo] {
    override def unbind: Todo = new Todo()
}
object HelloWorld extends BasicService[TodoBinding]("todoService", new TodoManager)
```

My problem is a compilation error that occurs inside the persist method of BasicService. On the last line, I get this:

```
Type mismatch: expected _$1, actual: IEntity
```

As I am a bit inexperienced with Scala, I might be missing something very obvious with the type system, but I genuinely cannot figure this out. How can I work around this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `BasicService` does not require that the type argument of `B`:

```
B <: Binding[_ <: IEntity]
```

is compatible with the type argument of `dataAccessObject`:

```
dataAccessObject: IDAO[_ <: IEntity]
```

What if one is `Binding[FooEntity]` and the other is `IDAO[BarEntity]`?

You should take that type variable `E` that you say you are trying to use, and actually define it:

```
class BasicService[E <: IEntity, B <: Binding[E]]
                  (serviceName: String, dataAccessObject: IDAO[E])
```

Also note that in the example code you posted, the type variable `B` to `BasicService` might not be necessary, because you only use it to receive the argument `binding` to `persist()`. You could have simply used the type `Binding[E]` there:

```
class BasicService[E <: IEntity]
                  (serviceName: String, dataAccessObject: IDAO[E]) {
  def persist(binding: Binding[E]): Unit = // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solves the problem. I am getting another error now ("No manifest available for B"), but it seems to be outside the scope of this question, as it occurs in a method I did not mention above. I will make a new question if necessary, and accept your answer as it is.

Comment: New question is here, for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285865/no-manifest-available-for-type-with-type-parameter