# Scala: "No manifest available for type T"

Tags: scala, generics, types

I am working on a Lift project with mixed Scala and Java code.

On the Java side, I have the following relevant items:

```
interface IEntity

interface IDAO<T extends IEntity> {
    void persist(T t);
}
```

On the Scala side, I have the following:

```
abstract class Binding[T <: IEntity] extends NgModel {
    def unbind: T
}

class BasicService[E <: IEntity](serviceName: String, dataAccessObject: IDAO[E]) {
      def render = renderIfNotAlreadyDefined(
        angular.module("myapp.services")
          .factory(serviceName,
            jsObjFactory()
              .jsonCall("persist", (binding: Binding[E]) => {  //<---COMPILATION ERROR
                  try {
                    dataAccessObject.persist(binding.unbind)
                    Empty
                   } catch {
                   case e: Exception => Failure(e.getMessage)
                   }
              })
          )
     )
}
```

This code will not compile. I get the following error at the point indicated above:

```
No Manifest available for Binding[E].
```

It is not clear at all to me why this occurs, but I am guessing it has something to do with this being a nested method invocation. The code compiles fine if I declare a member function with Binding[E] as a parameter, for example:

```
def someFunction(binding: Binding[E] = { // same code as above }
```

Why does this happen, and how can I work around it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213510/what-is-a-manifest-in-scala-and-when-do-you-need-it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Turns out this is relatively easily solved by implicitly passing on the manifest for the type in question, either in the constructor or the method itself:

```
class BasicService[E <: IEntity](serviceName: String, dataAccessObject: IDAO[E])(implicit m: Manifest[Binding[E]]) {
```

or

```
def render(implicit m: Manifest[Binding[E]])
```

Comment: can you show how do you initialise the implicit val?